# How to solve 'drivers/net/igbvf/igbvf.h:129:15: error: duplicate member 'page' '?

Tags: linux-kernel

I use ubuntu 11.10 64 bits and I run:

```
  sam@sam:~/download/kernel/linux-2.6.37.6$ make
    CHK     include/linux/version.h
    CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
    CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
    CHK     include/generated/compile.h
    VDSOSYM arch/x86/vdso/vdso-syms.lds
    VDSOSYM arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-int80-syms.lds
    VDSOSYM arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-syscall-syms.lds
    VDSOSYM arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-sysenter-syms.lds
    VDSOSYM arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-syms.lds
    LD      arch/x86/vdso/built-in.o
    LD      arch/x86/built-in.o
    CC [M]  drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.o
  In file included from drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.c:36:0:
  drivers/net/igbvf/igbvf.h:129:15: error: duplicate member 'page'
  make[3]: *** [drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.o] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [drivers/net/igbvf] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
  make: *** [drivers] Error 2
  sam@sam:~/download/kernel/linux-2.6.37.6$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

Comment: Did you change the sources in any way? Looks like `igbvf.h` has a syntax error.

Comment: I just download and compile. How to solve it? Thank you~ By the way, I can compile 2.6.38.8 without any error on the same computer.

Answer (score 5):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROBLEM:-1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gcc: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory
OBJCOPY arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-int80.so
objcopy: 'arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-int80.so.dbg': No such file
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/vdso/vdso32-int80.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/vdso] Error 2
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOLUTION:
----------
The problem is that gcc 4.6 doesn't support anymore linker-style architecture options.
Apply the following changes to solve the problem :
In arch/x86/vdso/Makefile :
replace "-m elf_x86_64" by "-m64" on the line starting with VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso.lds
replace "-m elf_i386" by "-m32" on the line starting with VDSO_LDFLAGS_vdso32.lds
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROBLEM:-2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
In file included from drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.c:36:0:
drivers/net/igbvf/igbvf.h: At top level:
drivers/net/igbvf/igbvf.h:129:15: error: duplicate member ‘page’
make[3]: *** [drivers/net/igbvf/ethtool.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drivers/net/igbvf] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/net] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOLUTION:
---------
struct igbvf_buffer {
dma_addr_t dma;
struct sk_buff *skb;`enter code here`
union {
/* Tx */
struct {
unsigned long time_stamp;
u16 length;
u16 next_to_watch;
u16 mapped_as_page;
};
/* Rx */
struct {
struct page *page; <--------------- No 1
u64 page_dma;
unsigned int page_offset;
};
};
struct page *page; <------------ No 2
};
Hmm conflict of a member with a transparent union.
Maybe older gccs didn't catch that. But it looks very broken
Comment second pointer.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROBLEM 3: Similar to Problem-2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
In file included from drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c:57:0:
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.h: At top level:
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.h:601:8: error: duplicate member ‘sense_buffer’
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c: In function ‘pmcraid_abort_cmd’:
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c:2940:33: warning: variable ‘res’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c: In function ‘pmcraid_ioctl_passthrough’:
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c:3745:5: warning: variable ‘access’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c: In function ‘pmcraid_check_ioctl_buffer’:
drivers/scsi/pmcraid.c:4052:6: warning: variable ‘access’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
make[3]: *** [drivers/scsi/pmcraid.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [drivers/scsi] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ashish/litmus-rt'
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOLUTION:
----------
Comment drivers/scsi/pmcraid.h:571
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```